# How to change "Dynamic Web Project" default source and output folders in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I change default values of "*source folders on build path*" and "*default output folder*" in "*Dynamic Web Project*" wizard in Eclipse, probably in the way as we do for "*Java Project*" in

> Windows > Preferences > Java > Build Path

The purpose is: each time I create new Dynamic Web Project, the wizard should show default source and output folders of my choice.
Since this option is available for Java project so I believe there should be something similar for Web Projects too but I am unable to find it. BTW I tried changing defaults of Java project but it does not effect dynamic web projects.

Answer (score 3):

Can you add web capabilities to your existing Java Project?

Also, [this](http://eclipse.dzone.com/tips/converting-java-project-dynami) is how to convert a Java Project by editing the .project file (different than how I remember doing it in Eclipse). That might give some insight into how to modify your .project file.

The [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/ccwebprj.html) seem to indicate that JavaSource is the property which dictates your Java source files for Dynamic Web Projects.

> JavaSource
>       Contains the project's Java source code for classes, beans, and servlets. When these resources are added to a Web project, they are automatically compiled and the generated files are added to the WEB-INF/classes directory. The contents of the source directory are not packaged in WAR files unless an option is specified when a WAR file is created.
>       Note: Though the default name given to the folder is JavaSources, you can change the name by right clicking on the name in the Project Explorer and clicking on Refactor > Rename.

Also, I think since a Dynamic Web Project is meant to adhere to J2EE  standards you can't change the path to the output folder in your project. You can however rename it if you want.

> WebContent folder
>       The mandatory location of all Web resources, including HTML, JSP, graphic files, and so on. If the files are not placed in this directory (or in a subdirectory structure under this directory), the files will not be available when the application is executed on a server. The Web content folder represents the contents of the WAR file that will be deployed to the server. Any files not under the Web content folder are considered development-time resources (for example, .java files, .sql files, and .mif files), and are not deployed when the project is unit tested or published.
>       Note: Though the default name given to the folder is WebContent, you can change the name in the Project Explorer by right-clicking the folder and selecting RefactorRename or from the Web page of the project's Properties dialog. In a dynamic Web project, changing the folder name will update the Java build output directory.

Comment: Thank you @duffleupugus for your answer but if I understood your answer correctly then we are on different pages. I don't want to change .project file or anything in existing project. Instead my requirement is to set default values in project creation wizard. This wizards always opens with preset source and output folder values that I have to change every time according to my needs. I was wondering can I change these default values so that next time I run new project wizard, I may see my choosen default source and output folders in the wizard pages?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy.

1.Create a text file named "org.eclipse.wst.web.prefs", add following config in it:

> # content directory, change the default name "WebContent" to
>   "webroot"
>
> webContent=webroot
>
> # make the default output of web project from %proj%\bin to
>   %webroot%\WEB-INF\classes
>
> useSingleRootStructure=true

2.Move it into %workspace%\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings.

3.Restart you eclipse.